# AngularJs $HTTP loop counter does not update

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have below code to pull data from HTTP service and bind JSON data to HTML,

This function was placed with a 2 seconds timer to pull automatically when ever there is a change in the backend.

```html
     function sampleDevices() {
    var devicesArray = [];

    for(id in devices) {
      var device = devices[id];

      var pollingApiUrl = "DBService.asmx/HelloWorld";

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: pollingApiUrl, params: { id: id } })
      .then(function (response) { // Success


              device.status= response.data.JsonStatus;
              device.comp = response.data.CompanyName;
              device.loc = response.data.ReceiverLocation});
    }
    $scope.devices = devicesArray;  }
<tr ng-repeat="device in devices |orderBy: '-event.rssi' limitTo: 3">
<td> {{device.comp}} </td>
<td> {{device.loc}} </td>
<td> {{device.test }} </td>
</tr>
```

I encounter a problem with response data, only last JSON success data always gets updated. 
for eg, output like

- A IN OK --1st time get the value and does not change
- B OUT OK  -- update the changes when occurring in back end

not able to get the correct response and bind the corresponding value to the list.
How to solve this issue, to get the value from JSON and update correct value to HTML tag with 2 or 3 seconds timer

Comment: First of all, what is the content of the variable `devices`? I don't see any declaration or assignment for it. Or is this just some example code then?

Comment: this is a just example of code, variable devices have some assigned value. for eg. id

Answer (score 0):

```
     function sampleDevices() {
    var devicesArray = [];
    var i=0;
    for(i=0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    var device = {};

      var pollingApiUrl = "DBService.asmx/HelloWorld";

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: pollingApiUrl, params: { id: devices[i].id } })
      .then(function (response) { // Success

              device.status= response.data.JsonStatus;
              device.comp = response.data.CompanyName;
              device.loc = response.data.ReceiverLocation;
                  devicesArray.push(device);
    });

    }
    $scope.devices = devicesArray;  }
<tr ng-repeat="device in devices |orderBy: '-event.rssi' limitTo: 3">
<td> {{device.comp}} </td>
<td> {{device.loc}} </td>
<td> {{device.test }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: use  track by $index, <tr ng-repeat="device in devices track by $index|orderBy: '-event.rssi' limitTo: 3">

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a http request multiple times in a for loop.

The for loop doesn't wait, it will trigger all requests in quick succession. To make the thing wait look into the async library and the each function https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

In the success cashback of async you would then set the scope.

Or... Change the backend so you only do one API call, this would be even better.

Comment: how to use async.each in http service call

Comment: Follow the link. You use async to loop over your results in as controlled manner. Under the it is a recursive function, basically meaning the iteration won't happen till you call it... From the http promise in this case.